# Postgres ClientWrite Event

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres 10.9 table that has ~200 million rows. This table has an index on one of the fields my_date which is obviously a Date. I'm executing the following query: `select my_date from my_table`.

The explain call yields the following:

```
Index Only Scan using client_purchaseorder_facility_alias_id_po_date_idx 
on client_purchaseorder  (cost=0.57..5981683.41 rows=196100256 width=4)
```

An extraordinary amount of time is spend (60%) in the ClientWrite event which I see whenever I perform the following query:

```
select pid, wait_event_type, wait_event 
from pg_stat_activity 
where wait_event is NOT NULL;
```

30% is in the DataFileRead.

Postgres documentation describes ClientWrite as "Waiting to write data to the client." Is there a way to tell why it is waiting? I'm performing the query from PGAdmin on a machine where not much else is going on. Total time to complete is at least 5 to 10 minutes. I feel that this should be going much faster.

I checked to see when the table was last vacuumed and it says two days ago.

Comment: Sending 200 million dates into PgAdmin to be parsed and stored and displayed takes some time (Why wouldn't it?).  I'm surprised PgAdmin can deal with it at all, I'd expect it to run out of memory and fall over long before finishing.  To see of PgAdmin itself is the bottleneck, could try something like `\copy (select ...) to '/dev/null'` from psql and see if that does any better.

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to display all 200 miliion rows at once? What are you looking to do, why not add a where clause?

Comment: @sharadov, i'm examining out database's performance. I don't want to examine all the rows at once. I could see a data science project later down the line that may want a fair range of data though.

Comment: @jjanes I think you're on to something. I tried psql and i didn't time it but it did seem significantly faster. great tip.

Comment: @mj_ for performance testing there are tools like pgbench  which will let you test out the performance based on your workloads and give you a sense of capacity needs for the data science project.

Comment: If you want to examine the performance of a query use `explain (analyze)` that will give you the real query's runtime without the overhead of sending the rows to the SQL client

Answer (score 2):

pgAdmin is known to be slow and inefficient with large result sets, so this is not surprising. It is not built for mass data display.

If you want to visualize a sample, add a `LIMIT` clause to the query.

If you want to export the data, use the `COPY` statement.